# Extend matrix or data frame to be quadratic having same row and column names

Tags: r, matrix

How can I easily extend a matrix or dataframe to be quadratic, i.e. has the same rows and column names. Where values are missing, I just want them to be zero.

Reproducable example:

```
cols<-c("A","B","D","F")
rows<-c("A","B","C", "E", "F")
data<-matrix(runif(20),nrow = length(rows), ncol = length(cols))
colnames(data)<-cols
rownames(data)<-rows
```

So the goal is to have a 6x6 matrix with column/rownames "A" to "F" and the values as in *data* and where missing, filled up with zeros.

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems a bit long-winded, but here's a little function that will generalize to any matrix with row names and column names:

```r
make_quadratic <- function(data)
{
  names <- sort(unique(c(colnames(data), rownames(data))))
  size  <- length(names)
  
 `colnames<-`(`rownames<-`(apply(apply(data, 1, 
  function(x) replace(numeric(size), names %in% colnames(data), x)), 1, 
  function(x) replace(numeric(size), names %in% rownames(data), x)),
  names), names)
}
```

So, for example:

```r
make_quadratic(data)
#>           A         B C         D E          F
#> A 0.1033626 0.4390343 0 0.9368352 0 0.47888726
#> B 0.3897981 0.1563756 0 0.3148652 0 0.79636682
#> C 0.6780338 0.4937433 0 0.1325104 0 0.10266721
#> D 0.0000000 0.0000000 0 0.0000000 0 0.00000000
#> E 0.7667374 0.1198529 0 0.8930371 0 0.35349412
#> F 0.1467854 0.4649394 0 0.5838215 0 0.05615008
```

---

**EDIT**

An alternative answer that does not include loops:

```r
i <- as.matrix(expand.grid(row = which(LETTERS[1:6] %in% rownames(data)),
                           col = which(LETTERS[1:6] %in% colnames(data))))

result <- matrix(0, nrow = 6, ncol = 6, 
                 dimnames = list(LETTERS[1:6], LETTERS[1:6]))

result[i] <- data

result
#>           A         B C         D E          F
#> A 0.1033626 0.4390343 0 0.9368352 0 0.47888726
#> B 0.3897981 0.1563756 0 0.3148652 0 0.79636682
#> C 0.6780338 0.4937433 0 0.1325104 0 0.10266721
#> D 0.0000000 0.0000000 0 0.0000000 0 0.00000000
#> E 0.7667374 0.1198529 0 0.8930371 0 0.35349412
#> F 0.1467854 0.4649394 0 0.5838215 0 0.05615008
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another base R option using nested `for` loop

```
nm <- sort(union(colnames(data),row.names(data)))
res <- `dimnames<-`(matrix(0,nrow = length(nm),ncol = length(nm)),replicate(2,nm,simplify = FALSE))
for (i in rows) {
  for (j in cols) {
    res[i,j] <- data[i,j]
  }
}
```

which gives

```
> res
           A         B C         D E          F
A 0.02778712 0.1386282 0 0.2263808 0 0.68144251
B 0.52731078 0.3214921 0 0.1314165 0 0.09916910
C 0.88031907 0.1548316 0 0.9815635 0 0.11890256
D 0.00000000 0.0000000 0 0.0000000 0 0.00000000
E 0.37306337 0.1322282 0 0.3270137 0 0.05043966
F 0.04795913 0.2213059 0 0.5069395 0 0.92925392
```

Comment: You would think there should be a better approach than either of our looping solutions Thomas, but I just can't see one.

Comment: @AllanCameron Good point! I saw your efforts, nice solution using `expand.grid`, upvoted for your answer!